# Is there a Blender Certification?

Tags: documentation

Could you please tell me if Blender offers a certification like Java Language, HTML, CSS or other software?

Answer (score 8):

There is a [certification program for Blender Trainers](https://www.blender.org/certification/). You can become a certified instructor BFCT if you ingress in that certification program.

Maintaing a certifications cost an [additional 50€ a year](https://www.blendernetwork.org/certification/become-a-trainer/), the same as a Freelance subscription to Blender Network